# Trouble reading grouped messages from the MQ adapter using BPEL

Tags: xml, xsd, ibm-mq, bpel, oracle-fusion-middleware

Having trouble de-queueing message through MQ adapter in the BPEL. There are multiple messages grouped in the queue. Probably the error is caused by not defining NXSD schema properly.

I am getting the below error:

> Error while translating. Error while translating. Error while
>   translating, with error message : "minOccurs not satisfied.
>   minOccurs="1" not satisfied for the node "`<element name="Rows">`".
>   Loop terminated with cardinality "0". Insufficient or invalid data.
>   Please correct the NXSD schema. ". Correct the reported problem if
>   possible. Contact oracle support if error is not fixable.

The XSD defined for the MQ adapter is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:nxsd="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/nxsd"
            xmlns:tns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            elementFormDefault="qualified"
            attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
            nxsd:version="NXSD"
            nxsd:stream="chars"
            nxsd:encoding="UTF-8">
  <xsd:element name="Rows">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Messages"  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="Message"  type="xsd:string"
                           nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="${eol}"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Sounds like it's not finding any `Rows` elements.  Anyway to see what's in the queue?  The error is a bit odd, in any case, because the message won't even be well-formed if there's not a single `Rows` root element.  It's not like you can change the `minOccurs` value to `0` for the root element.